# Is there a way to cleanly avoid duplicate code in this instance?

Tags: java, android, class, duplicates, mvp

I'm working on android with Java and I'm implementing the Model-View-Presenter architecture. There are two types of games the player can play:

- Game A
- Game B

Both games are really similar but with each their respective .class documents and (e.g. *GameA.class and a GameB.class*).

In both cases, their respective presenters are the same, with **the only thing changing being the instantiation & declaration of the model class**. For example:

GameAPresenter.class:

```
class GameAPresenter{

    private GameA game;
    // other stuff here that happens in both presenters

    GameAPresenter(int par1, int par2){
        this.game = new GameA(par1, par2);
        //other stuff here that happens in both presenters

    }
}
```

GameBPresenter.class:

```
class GameBPresenter{

    private GameB game;
    // other stuff here that happens in both presenters

    GameBPresenter(int par1, int par2){
        this.game = new GameB(par1, par2);
        //other stuff here that happens in both presenters

    }
}
```

Is there any way I can cleanly avoid having duplicate code, simulated by the single-line comments? 
Bonus if I can make both models share the one presenter.

Comment: Questions about code review should be asked at [codereview.se]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are gonna want to create a generic `Game` class that `GameA` and `GameB` can then both inherit from.

Same can go with the `GamePresenter`, create a generic one that `GamePresenterA` and `GamePresenterB` can inherit from. Also you can give the `GamePresenter` a `Game` everytime you create a new instance of it or call a certain method. That way there can be a single `GamePresenter` and it can take whatever `Game` to present it.

Comment: Consider whether `Game` should be an interface instead of a superclass. Also, `Game` doesn't need to be generic here, and `GamePresenter` may not need to be generic either; polymorphism is probably enough. It may turn out that only one `GamePresenter` class is needed after all.

Comment: Alright, thanks a lot [kaya3](https://stackoverflow.com/users/12299000/kaya3), to be honest, I am not great with the technical terms. Thanks for the recommendation :D

Comment: To add to @kaya3's comment.  We tend to [prefer composition over inheritance](https://stackoverflow.com/q/49002/42962).

Comment: Sorry guys, but I really want to expand my knowledge in this area, is this mainly design patterns and software engineering ?

Comment: This fits perfectly into the abstraction I was going to create tomorrow when I'll be refactoring my code. Thank you for the great answer Nizar!

Comment: @Nizar This is definitely about OO design, yes; I'd call it a more general design issue than one about design patterns specifically, but perhaps there is a named pattern which applies in this case. Design is often considered a part of software engineering, yes.